# Getting Postman unsupportedMediatype error when uploading files to s3 Bucket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, postman

I am trying to upload Images to aws s3 bucket. but i got unsupportedMediaType 415 error in postman. Not getting, where Its going wrong. Could you help me out?
postman formdata request => taking file, fileName, and Id

In service.js file:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');

const bucketName = process.env.bucketName;
// Initiating S3 instance
const s3 = new aws.S3({
    secretAccessKey: process.env.bucketSecretAccessKey,
    accessKeyId: process.env.bucketAccessKeyId,
    region: process.env.region
});
// Options you can choose to set to accept files upto certain size limit
// const options = {partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 1};

module.exports = {
 upload: async function(payload)  {
          let fileContent = fs.readFileSync(payload.file)
          const params = {
              Bucket: bucketName, 
              ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
              Key: payload.client_id/payload.familyName/payload.fileName, 
              Body: fileContent
           };
           let fileResp = null;
           await s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {
               if (err) {
                   console.log(err)
                   throw err;
               }
               fileResp = data;
               console.log(`File uploaded successfully. ${data.Location}`);
           });
           return fileResp;
  },
};
```

I am trying to upload Images to aws s3 bucket. but i got unsupportedMediaType 415 error in postman. Not getting, where Its going wrong. Could you help me out?
postman formdata request => taking file, fileName, and Id

Api call through url:

```````````````````````````````````````````
  uploadImage : async function(req, h) {
        try{
             let responseFile = null;
            const uploadImage = await s3.upload(req.payload).then( async (resp) => {
                    responseFile = {fileUrl: resp.Location};
                if(!!responseFile){
                    const updateFileName = await Family.updateOne({_id: req.payload.id},{
                        image: req.payload.fileName,
                        fileLocation : resp.Location
                    });
                    console.log(updateFileName)
                }
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                    responseFile = err.message;
                });
        } catch (error) {
                console.error(error.message);
            return h.response({ error: responseMessages.internal_server_error }).code(500);
        }
    },
})
``````````````````````````````````````````

postman response:
`````````````````````
{
    "statusCode": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Unsupported Media Type"
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggHCj.png
```````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 0):

Use below

```
  const params = {
              Bucket: bucketName, 
              Key: `${payload.client_id}/${payload.familyName}/${payload.fileName}`,
              Body: fileContent
           };
```

There are two issues

1. Key. path is not correct
2. Content-type is not required

follow above snippet and try

Comment: I added this key, but still i got the same error.

Comment: Can you share response. is it same as {
    "statusCode": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Unsupported Media Type"
}

Comment: yes, same response.

Comment: It seems like there is restriction set on s3 bucket. can you check bucket policies. here is the link to restrict certain filetypes https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-allow-certain-file-types/ . may be it is enabled. try to disable it.

Comment: i didnt add any bucket policy here.

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::rubic-dev-images/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadPObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::rubic-dev-images/*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: I have added this bucketpolicy now, but still i got same error.

Answer (score 0):

payload: {
output: 'stream',
parse: true,
allow: 'multipart/form-data',
multipart: true,
timeout: false,
},

I have added this payload in my route.js file, then it worked for me.